# Ubuntu doesn't start on GIGABYTE Z270 motherboard

Tags: 16.04, drivers

I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 on my new Gigabyte GA-Z270-HD3P on my new Gigabyte GA-Z270-HD3P motherboard/mainboard that has an Intel CORE i5 6600 and no graphics card.  After the start screen appears, the installation stops and the video signal gets cut off.

Is this chipset compatible with Linux?  Is there something that I can do to get my system working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Those that had video cards needed UEFI setting.  "IGFX" instead of "PCI Slot 1" http://askubuntu.com/questions/792012/nvidia-geforce-gtx970-problem-ubuntu-16-04 So do you have correct UEFI setting? Also older Gigabyte boards need UEFI setting for IOMMU changed and boot parameter for iommu added. Some Gigabyte boards need acpi=off boot parameter also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=5

Comment: This is using **Intel HD Graphics 530**, eh?

Comment: Yes, I have no graphic card

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with ASUS PRIME Z270-AR and Core i7 7700K.
I switched to 16.10 and it installed without issue.