# Can't boot ubuntu from USB device

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, uefi, usb-installation

so today I decided to quit windows and starting using Ubuntu in a daily basis.
First of all I'd like to apologize if this is a duplicated post, but I've searched all over stackexchange and found noone with the same errors I have.
So I went to Ubuntu's website, grabbed the [16.04.3 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) version, looked for a [tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0), followed every step to create the bootable USB, booted from it and selected the option Install Ubuntu.
And then got stuck on a scary screen that made me realize that something was not right.
I'm gonna try to illustrate the process as best as I can:

1. First I selected on my ["F12 screen"](https://i.gyazo.com/de71fcd88ea5fa3a94e9110d2d63207a.jpg) from what disk I wanted to boot my PC.
   NOTE: First I tried the KINGSTONDataTraveler (Without the UEFI) and I got an error message along the lines of "Reboot and select a proper Boot Device, or insert boot media device and press a key", so I rebooted and selected the UEFI one.
2. Then on my second screen I got the [usual install-or-try Ubuntu menu](https://i.gyazo.com/e6e40a139fd1b898873fb78a392a7296.jpg). So I went and clicked Install Ubuntu. Everything looks fine for now.
3. And here it comes all the trouble...
   My monitor remains black for a good 4-6 seconds, and then [this](https://i.gyazo.com/33cb608da8943c0b406e50b01fa50079.jpg) strange dotted line appears on top of the screen.
   And like 2 or 3 seconds later my screen gets filled with [this](https://i.gyazo.com/054300bb07d5261b6a1033457af38dbd.jpg), what looks like a VERY distorted set of characters.

My screen remains stuck with that pattern indefinitely, so I need to power off my computer directly from my power button.
I tried reflashing the USB drive, tried others USB drives, re-downloaded the iso file to make sure it was not corrupted. Pretty much everything I can think of...
I don't know what to do now, any suggestion?
These are my computer specs:
`Motherboard: Gigabyte Z97X-Gaming 3
CPU: Intel Core i7-4790K 4.0Ghz
GPU: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 970 WindForce 3X OC 4GB DDR5
RAM: G.Skill Trident X DDR3 2400 PC3-19200 16GB 2x8GB CL10 
SSD: (1x) Samsung EVO 850 Series 250 GB
SSD2: (1x) Samsung EVO 840 Series 250 GB
HDDs: (2x) WD Blue 1TB`

NOTE: When I was on windows, my 2 SSD and my 2 HDD were on raid 0 (2 on 2).
I don't know if I'm missing something, hope that's enough to solve my problem.

Comment: I think there  is a problem with the driver for your graphics card. **Try the boot option `nomodeset`**. You can add a boot option according to this link (and links from it), http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808

Comment: Please see [https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/283721) - it will also describe using the nomodeset as described by @sudodus

Answer (score 1):

@sudodus got the answer right.
For anyone facing the same problem as mine, using <kbd>nomodeset</kbd> as the booting option allowed me to start the installation process.
That's done pressing <kbd>e</kbd> on the GRUB menu and editing the command replacing ***quiet splash*** with ***nomodeset*** and leaving everything else as it is. Once that's done just press <kbd>Ctrl + x</kbd> to boot into the installer.
Hope that this works for you!
--------------------------------------
EDIT:
After booting for first time into ubuntu after installing it the same graphical bug appeared, not allowing me to do anything with my new OS, not even upgrading my Nvidia drivers.
So after a bit more research [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792012/nvidia-geforce-gtx970-problem-ubuntu-16-04/792405#792405) allowed me to boot into Ubuntu with my Motherboard's GPU.
As for upgrading my drivers [this guide](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux) helped a lot.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) The next step could be to install a proprietary nvidia driver in the installed system.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks for your help mate! I have intalled ubuntu already, the problem now is that I can't boot to it due to the same graphics problmems... Gonna try to sort that out now

Comment: Yes, the first guess in that you have the same problem in the installed system as in the live system, and the first step is to use nomodeset. The second step (when some basic graphics work), is to try to install a proprietary nvidia graphics driver. Maybe the following link will help you (see the accepted answer), https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics