# Install issues with 19.04 on Gigabyte motherboard

Tags: boot, system-installation, 19.04

Currently I'm trying to install 19.04 on my fairly new computer, with a Gigabyte GA-z270 motherboard. When attempting to install, I will get the purple splash screen, the orange/white dots will show up briefly, and then my computer will stop outputting video. After this failed attempt, my motherboard no longer recognizes my flash drive.

Comment: What video card? Are you booting in UEFI boot mode? Do you have latest UEFI from Gigabyte? SSD or HDD? My similar z170 required some setting changes in UEFI. Secure Boot off. UEFI on & CSM off. Fast start up off. Others: Gigabyte Z170 Nvidia 970 16.04   UEFI Settings required                         
http://askubuntu.com/questions/792012/nvidia-geforce-gtx970-problem-ubuntu-16-04 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2341704

Comment: After checking settings, it does appear that I'm booting in UEFI mode. Currently running a GTX 1060, and trying to install onto an HDD.

Comment: Your nVidia card will need nomodeset. And latest Ubuntu may install nVidia driver if you check install proprietary drivers. In not you have to use nomodeset on first boot and install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. UEFI boot:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & nVidia: https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap Add nomodeset: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it See UEFI/grub not old BIOS screen.